Travel to Schengen zone for tourism with "visite pro" business visa
I'm from China but live in the UK. I was just recently issued a Schengen visa for 6 months from France. I applied for business purposes, but I want to leave France and later on travel to other countries in the Schengen zone for tourism purposes.
I see other answers on this site and elsewhere saying that once you actually have the visa there is no difference, but many of those answers are quite old and unlike my previous Schengen visa, this one specifically says "visite pro" (professional visit), so perhaps the situation has changed and they're now enforcing the specific visa types. If so, I imagine border officials might ask what business I'm visiting for.
Is it possible to travel with this business visa for tourism during the 6 month multi entry period? If not, if I applied for a tourism visa for within that same window would they issue it?

if I applied for a tourism visa for within that same window would they issue it? You can only apply for another visa to start on/after your current visa expiry date, AFAIK you can’t have two multiple entry ‘C’ visas at the same time.

I have first hand experience probably not relevant, the American passport holder was asked where was he going and he was let go and in my turn he asked me what I am a doing here and when leaving and asked me to show proofs , so you should better be prepared to answer the questions and honestly having a visa doesn’t mean entry is guaranteed if the officer things the visit is not reliable refusal to entry , but it largely depends on why you going and not give too many confusing answers


Is it possible to travel with this business visa for tourism during the 6 month multi entry period?

Only if you have used your first entry

so perhaps the situation has changed and they're now enforcing the specific visa types

The purpose only applies for your first entry. After your first entry, purpose of visit can be anything (as long as it is in the country's short stay rules).
Purpose is only recorded in the non-standard remarks field and not in any standard field.

What is this based on? It seems much more murky than this.

@Relaxed The purpose is in remarks (non-standard field), and Schengen visa code makes no difference between business and tourist visits. Only the country you visit for your first entry is likely to care about the purpose (just as with going to another country than the country of issuance). It's called uniform visa by the Visa Code after all

Yeah, I obviously know that it's an all-purpose visa, I wrote about it many times, which is why I am wondering what your reasoning is to present this first-visit thing as a rule when the Visa Code says nothing of the sort.
